# How ** prompt differs from * prompt?

Tags: tex-core

According to *TeXbook* p. 23, the `**` prompt differs from `*` prompt only when first character is `&` or non-`\`.

However, if we issue the following command (notice the first `\`) in `**` and `*` prompts, the output is different:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{a} \showbox0
```

Why is the output different? Where is this documented? Are there any other cases when processing of `**` differs from `*`?

Comment: By "output" please clarify that you mean the log file versus terminal. The typeset output is the same.

Comment: As a hint, try `**\setbox0=\hbox{\jobname} \showbox0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> touch ilif.tex # we have a suitable file to input
>>> tex ilif # a file name has been given
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
(./ilif.tex)
*\setbox0=\hbox{a} \showbox0
! OK (see the transcript file).
<*> \setbox0=\hbox{a} \showbox0

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on ilif.log.
>>> tex # no file name
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
**\setbox0=\hbox{a} \showbox0
> \box0=
\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x5.00002
.\tenrm a

! OK.
<*> \setbox0=\hbox{a} \showbox0

? x
No pages of output.
```

In the second case there is no `.log` file open yet, because TeX is still waiting for a file name in order to set the `\jobname`. As you see, in the second case there is no annotation `Transcript written on`. Since no other output stream is open, TeX will use the terminal for printing diagnostics.

If you follow Donald Arsenau's hint and do `\setbox0=\hbox{\jobname} \showbox0`, the presence of `\jobname` will force TeX to assign the default `\jobname`, that is, `texput`. In this case the `.log` file can be opened and the output on the terminal is the same as in the `ilif.tex` case.